# Do I need to constantly wear the Blue Seal?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I joined the "Way of the Blue" covenant and my understanding is that I need to wear the "Blue seal" I received in order to get help if invaded. What I'd like to know is: do I have to wear it **before** the invasion starts or it will work even if I wear it when the enemy is already in my world?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the source, but I remember reading somewhere that you can put the Blue Seal ring on after an invasion and still summon a Blue Phantom. The ring does confer a 3% hp bonus when worn, however, making it a useful ring on its own.